# Why does text_decoration:none isn't working?

Tags: html, css, django

my text-decoration in main.css didn't work. I tried to change place of tags and to add this tag an several times but it didn't work too. but it didn't work.

!important didn't work. I dunno what to do else.

Tysm in advance!

CSS code:

```
body {
    background: #2c2c2c;
}

aside {
    float: left;
    background: #181818;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 2.5%;
    height: 100vh;
    color: #fff;
    border-right: 5px solid #4d4d4d;
}

aside img {
    width: 80px;
    float: left;
}

aside .logo {
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    top: -5px;
}

aside h3 {
    margin-top: 50px;
    font-size: 28px;
}

aside ul {list-style: none}
aside ul li {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    transition: transform .6s ease;
}

li {text-decoration: none !important;}

aside ul li:hover, aside ul a:hover {
    color: #eb5959;
    transform: scale(1.05);
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

HTML code:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>{% block title %}{%endblock%}</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'main/css/main.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">
</head>
<body>
  <aside>
    <img src="{% static 'main/img/logo(2).png' %}" alt="Лого">
    <span class="logo">DecSam</span>
    <h3>Навигация</h3>
    <ul>
      <a href=""><li><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Главная</li></a>
      <a href=""><li><i class="fas fa-address-book"></i>Про нас</li></a>
      <a href="mailto:decsam@mail.com"><li><i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i>Связаться с нами</li></a>
    </ul>
  </aside>
  <main>
    {% block content%}
    {% endblock %}
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should put the 'a' tag inside the 'li' not the other way around in the aside block

Comment: it helped. tysm!

Answer (score -2):

Just Replace Your CSS Line:

li {text-decoration: none !important;}
Your Code not Correct Replace with the following code

```css
aside a {text-decoration: none;}
```

```html
 <aside>
<img src="{% static 'main/img/logo(2).png' %}" alt="Лого">
<span class="logo">DecSam</span>
<h3>Навигация</h3>
<ul>
  <a href=""><li><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Главная</li></a>
  <a href=""><li><i class="fas fa-address-book"></i>Про нас</li></a>
  <a href="mailto:"><li><i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i>Связаться с нами</li></a>
</ul>
  </aside>
```

Comment: Please, use code formatting tools, otherwise it's quite hard to differentiate the code from the regular text